Let $\{Q(t), t\ge 0\}$ be a stochastic process. Is $ E\left[\int_0^{\infty} dQ(t) \right] = \int_0^{\infty} d\{EQ(t)\}$?
Let $\{Q(t), t \ge 0\}$ be a martingale. Is it true that under some regularity conditions (so one can apply Fubini theorem)
$$
E\left[\int_0^{\infty} dQ(t) \right] = \int_0^{\infty} dE\{Q(t)\}?
$$
Given that a martingale has a constant mean, there exists a constant $c$ such that $E\{Q(t)\} = c$ for all $t \ge 0$. However, I am unsure how to interpret the integral $\int_0^{\infty} dc$. Specifically, since $c$ is a constant, its differential $dc$ is zero, making the entire integral zero.
I understand that this relates to the topics of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals and stochastic processes. I would appreciate any recommended resources on this subject.

Yes, $dc=0$ so RHS is $0$. LHS is $E[Q(\infty)-Q(0)]$ if $Q(\infty)=\lim_{t \to \infty} Q(t)$ exists a.s. This is also $0$ if the martingale converges in mean.

@geetha290krm: But by that same token, we can see that the statement is not true if the integral doesn't converge to mean.  For instance, if $Q(t)$ is Brownian motion started at 0 and stopped upon hitting 1, the RHS is 1 but as you say the LHS is 0.
